# LLVM Induction Variable Simplify Pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want to have only canonical induction variable in my IR before I pass it to one of my other passes to do some transformation.

However the pass -indvars doesn't seem to do it. How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found out that -indvars pass now don't canonicalize induction variable because most other passes now are made to work without need for canonical loops.

However my pass required that loops be in canonical form, so I found the old induction variable simplify pass and explicitly included in my file.

You too can include that old pass to get your work done. You can find old pass [here](http://opensource.apple.com/source/clang/clang-137/src/lib/Transforms/Scalar/IndVarSimplify.cpp)